# How to change size of the segment .text for file ELF ARM EABI?

Tags: assembly, arm, elf, segment, eabi

I have ELF ARM EABI file without sources. It binary .so file.

How to expand size of the segment .text of the file?

I know this break code in this binary, but it is not a problem now.

Comment: Use `objcopy` and adjust the LMA/VMA (possibly have to do that for sections after `.text` too). Alternatively, extract the `.text` into a file, copy the remainder to a new file, then add the an enlarged `.text` back.